# Clip path goes in front of other background

Tags: html, background-color

So basically i'm making html website with background and clip path, i wonder why does my clip path goes in front of every other color background.

I did it like this :

```
<div class="clippath1"></div>
<div class="clippath2"></div>
<div class="main">
    <nav>
        <img src="images/logo.png">
        <ul>
            <li class='menu'><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li class='menu'><a href="/">Location</a></li>
            <li class='menu'><a href="/">Products</a></li>
            <li class='menu'><a href="/">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="content">
        ----------
    </div>
</div>
<div class="bottom-background">
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

set *.clip-path* element CSS position property to **absolute** or **fix**
like:

```
.clippath1 { position: fixed; }
```

Comment: still doesn't work, the issue wasn't the position. but all my text, behind of those clippath